# Как начать программировать на OpenGL

Tags: c++, c, opengl, gcc

Вообщем, задумал начать программировать 3д-графику и взгляд пал на OpenGL. Не долго думая, вбил в поиск: "Download OpenGL SDK". Перейдя по первой ссылке (https://www.opengl.org/sdk/), понял, что не всё так просто. Скачивал GLEW, так там библиотеки в разрешение ".lib". Скачал GLFW, решил скомпилировать пример, так у меня нету GLAD. Долго искал GLAD, но безуспешно. Так и не понял, что такое OpenGL и как начать его использовать.

Comment: Начните лучше с DirectX, для которого действительно существует SDK, а поплясать с бубном opengl можно будет и потом, по необходимости.

Comment: Начните вот тут, например: https://learnopengl.com/ отличный ресурс по обучению OpenGL

Comment: "Скачивал GLEW, так там библиотеки в разрешение ".lib"." - а что не так?

Comment: @insolor Дело в том, что я долгое время использовал gcc и старался избегать возможности перехода в vs, однако, похоже, что иного выхода нет :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Поскольку сам OpenGL - всего лишь спецификация - описание интерфейсов, сигнатур и функциональности (и ни слова о том, как это должно быть реализовано), то для каждой ОС OpenGL - свой (общим будет лишь код, который написан с использованием  OpenGL).

Базово, для работы с OpenGL нужны 2 вещи: контекст (каковым, обычно, является окно) и библиотека для работы с ним.

И самый быстрый вариант получить вожделенный OpenGL на Windows - [Visual Studio](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/ru/thank-you-downloading-visual-studio/?sku=Community&rel=16) + [vcpkg](https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg): скачиваем и устанавливаем и то, и другое (также, vcpkg позволяет устанавливать и кучу других библиотек). Думаю, установка студии не представляет сложности, поэтому остановлюсь на пакетном менеджере, который стоит установить после Visual Studio: можно варварски (без гита) скачать с гитхаба, кнопкой "code" / "download zip" - архивчик и вытряхнуть его куда-нибудь (в любую папку), после чего нужно найти и запомнить папку с файликом bootstrap-vcpkg.bat. Нужно будет запустить bootstrap-vcpkg.bat (можно просто кликнуть, а можно запустить из командной строки cmd.exe - последний вариант каноничнее):

```
cd <папка в которой лежит bootstrap-vcpkg.bat>
bootstrap-vcpkg.bat
```

Дальше, соберётся vcpkg - в папке с bootstrap-vcpkg.bat появится vcpkg.exe. Вот он-то нам и потребуется: снова открываем командную строку, переходим в папку с bootstrap-vcpkg.bat и (теперь) vcpkg.exe:

```
cd <папка в которой лежат bootstrap-vcpkg.bat и vcpkg.exe>
```

Дальше, не закрывая командную строку, вводим следующие заклинания (если ОС 32 битная, то пишем x86, иначе x64; ниже пишу для 64х разрядной винды):

```
vcpkg inststall glfw3:x64-windows-static
vcpkg inststall glfw3:x64-windows
vcpkg inststall glbinding:x64-windows-static
vcpkg inststall glbinding:x64-windows
vcpkg integrate install
```

После чего будут установлены: [GLFW3](https://www.glfw.org/documentation.html) для создания окна (подойдёт и для Windows, и для Linux, и для MacOS) и [glbinding](https://github.com/cginternals/glbinding), который позволяет использовать OpenGL (разница между тем, что в примерах и glbinding - лишь в том, что всё, что в glbinding надо доставать из пространства имён gl и иногда отключать через #undef некоторые константы, т.к. они уже есть в glbinding).

Короче, в итоге получится что-то такое (подразумеваю C++17):

```
#include <glbinding/gl/gl.h>
#include <glbinding/glbinding.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
   glfwInit(); // Самая простая инициализация GLFW3
   auto window = glfwCreateWindow(640, 480, "Hello World", NULL, NULL); // Самый простой вариант создания окна с помощью GLFW#
   glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);// Указываем OpenGL работать с данным окном
   glbinding::initialize(glfwGetProcAddress); // Инициализируем glbinding, с помощью glfwGetProcAddress из GLFW3 (чтобы glbinding "знал" где какие функции OpenGL)


   // С этого момента, можно вызывать функции OpenGL, 
   // при необходимости вызывая #undef для констант OpenGL, 
   // которые могут высыпаться из GLFW3, но которые не 
   // понимает glbinding; 
   // весь OpenGL находится в пространстве имён gl в glbinding,
   // поэтому перед всем, что относится к OpenGL может быть нужно писать gl:: (или можно написать using namespace gl; или можно написать using gl::<то, что хотим из OpenGL)
  

   // Дальше типовая реализация:

   gl::glClearColor(0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1); // Задаём цвет экрана серый (r, g, b, a)
   while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window)) {// Пока окно открыто
     glfwPollEvents(); // Проверяем события окна
#undef GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT // т.к. может вывалиться из GLFW3 - то о чём писал выше
     gl::glClear(gl::GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT); // Очищаем экран

     // Тут прописываем обновление экрана с помощью OpenGL

     glfwSwapBuffers(window); // Обновляем графику, согласно тому, что мы указали OpenGL 
   }
   glfwTerminate(); // Очищаем всякое барахло
}
```

Answer (score 2):

OpenGL - отличный выбор. Я бы посоветовал OpenGL ES (как более кросс-платформенный).
Низко-уровневый вариант - OpenGL ES 3.2.
Специально скачивать его не надо. Просто Visual Studio достаточно.
У меня - VS 2022. Для Windows понадобятся еще GLFW и GLAD.
На Андроиде работает и так.
Свой собственный опыт я постарался изложить тут:
https://writingagame.ru/
Получилось типа пошаговой обучалки.
Тема: GameDev, 3D, C++, Visual Studio, OpenGL ES, cross-platform (Android / Windows). Бесплатно.

Comment: К данному вопросу этот ответ вполне подходит, и сайт вроде выглядит адекватно. Однако не стоит заниматься спаммерством и постить ссылку на свой сайт во всех хоть чем-то связанных вопросах.

Comment: Понял. Спасибо. Постараюсь не злоупотреблять.